# why direct typecast doesn't work in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a field `response['additional-info']` of type `string`. Its structure is of a `json`.

`"{"supported-tags":[{"s1":"someS1","s2":"someS2","s3":"someS3"}]}"`

I want to convert ti some type `B`.

`B` is

```
export class C{
  constructor(
    public s1:string,
    public s2:string,
    public s3:string
  ){}
}

export class B{
  'supported-tags':Array<C>;
  constructor(
    supportedTags:Array<C>
  ){
    this['supported-tags'] = supportedTags;
  }
}
```

I notice that direct typecasting doesn't work

```
let b:B = <B>response['additional-info'] //doesn't work
let b:B = response['additional-info'] as B //doesn't work
```

but

```
let b:B = <B><any>response['additional-info'] //works
```

and of course this works

```
let b:B = JSON.parse(response['additional-info']) // work
```

I can understand what the last two works but why 1st 2 doesn't?

Comment: What does `B` look like?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: What do you mean by "works" and "doesn't work"?

Comment: when I do `<B>response['additional-info']`, IDE complains that `string` cannot be converted to `B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Type casting" in TypeScript does not work like in other languages and actually, it's called "type assertion".

From [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but **performs no special checking or restructuring of data**. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you need.

So, it's completely expected that you have to transform the data manually (with `JSON.parse()` in your case).

Comment: but if I am telling Typescript that " I know what I am doing" then why does the IDE complain when I do <B>response['additional-info']. I get error that `string` cannot be converted to `B`

Comment: Because TS knows for a fact that a `string` is not a `B`. On the other hand, when doing `<B><any>response['additional-info']`, you first tell TS that `response['additional-info']` can be anything, then there exists a possibility for it to be a `B` (theoretically)... but it doesn't mean that it's going to work at runtime.